# Вывод пароля в форму

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

В админке список пользователей, когда редактирую пользователя вывожу емаил, имя, и пароль. В форму пользователя из контроллера отправляю как сущность. Все поля заполняются кроме `password`. Если менять `type='password'` на `type='text'` поле заполняется. Как можно вывести поле `password` c `type='password'`?

Comment: Там хэш, да даже хоть не хэш. Мне надо чтоб поле было заполнено символами для проверки валидации дальше. Иначе пустое поле

Comment: Значит надо валидацию изменять а не придумывать костыли на форме вывода. есть символы в поле - запускается их валидация, нет - значит все и так в порядке, ничего с этим значением не будет происходить.

Comment: А есть пример как в зендовской валидации это применить? Искал подобное не нашел. Или в проверке поля можно указывать сразу, что поле может быть пустым и минимальное значение допустим 6 символов?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте атрибут value=выводимое значение